# Is the relation on $\Bbb R \times\Bbb Z$ given by $(a,b) \sim (c,d) \iff (\exists t \ne0)(\exists n \in \Bbb Z)(c = at \land b^2 = 3n+d^2)$ symmetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, relations

> Check if $R$  defined on $\mathbb R \times \mathbb Z$ is symmetric, when
> $$(a,b) \sim (c,d) \iff (\exists t \ne0)(\exists n \in \mathbb Z)(c = at \land b^2 = 3n+d^2)$$

I have attempted to solve this but I got stuck very quickly. If $R$ was symmetric, then it would imply that

\begin{align*}
&(\exists t\ne0)(\exists n \in \mathbb Z)(c = at \land b^2 = 3n+d^2) \\
\implies &(\exists t_2 \ne 0)(\exists m \in \mathbb Z)(a = ct_2 \land d^2 = b^2 + 3m)
\end{align*}
Is enough to set $t_2 = \frac 1 t$ and $3n = -3m$?

Comment: Yes, that would be enough. Good job!

Comment: More carefully, $n-m$ rather than $3n=-3m$

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, yes, that's enough. Let's rephrase this in a bit clearer of a fashion: assume the following is true:

$$(a,b) \sim (c,d), \text{ i.e. } (\exists t \in \Bbb R \setminus \{0\})(\exists n \in \mathbb Z)(c = at \land b^2 = 3n+d^2)$$

We want to show, on the premise of the above, the following is true:

$$(c,d) \sim (a,b), \text{ i.e. } (\exists t' \in \Bbb R \setminus \{0\})(\exists n' \in \mathbb Z)(a = ct' \land d^2 = 3n'+b^2)$$

To show the existence of $t',n'$, we can simply define them and observe that it works. Namely,

$$c = at \iff \frac 1 a = \frac t c \iff a = \frac 1 t c$$

which suggests the choice of $t' = 1/t$. Similarly,

$$b^2 = 3n + d^2 \iff \frac{b^2-d^2}{3} = n \iff \frac{d^2-b^2}{3} = -n$$

which suggests the choice of $n' = -n$. Of course, since $t \ne 0$, then $1/t \ne 0$; likewise, since $n \in \Bbb Z$, then $-n \in \Bbb Z$. It is also obvious by construction that these definitions of $t',n'$ otherwise satisfy the conditions, validating them.

Thus your relation is indeed symmetric.

---

*Mostly just posting this to get this out of the unanswered queue. Posting as Community Wiki in particular since I have nothing further to add.*